# Inserir valores em mais de 1 formulário dinamicamente com formsy-react

Tags: javascript, react, front-end

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação em ReactJS e atualmente tenho 6 formulários (estou utilizando o formsy-react) que são inseridos de forma dinâmica, preciso inserir informações nos inputs de um determinado form, porém não achei nenhuma forma de fazer isso mesmo lendo a documentação. Alguém sabe como fazer?

```
 const upForm = () => {
    let result = {};


  for (const item of data) {
        result[`value[${item.id_pl_indicator}]`] = item.value;
    }

    setTimeout(() => {
        formRef.current.updateInputsWithValue({ ...result })
    }, 100);
 }
```

Mas ele não insere em nenhum form, parece estar 'perdido'.

Alguém sabe como poderia fazer?

Answer (score -2):

Se você quer que o `<input />` do seu formulário já inicie com um valor específico, você deve utilizar o atributo `value`.

De acordo com este trecho da [documentação do formsy](https://github.com/formsy/formsy-react/blob/master/API.md#value) você pode fazer isso de forma semelhante utilizando a props, de mesmo nome, `value`.

Estes links podem te ajudar [componentes controlados](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) e [componentes não controlados](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#:%7E:text=Com%20um%20componente%20n%C3%A3o%20controlado,defaultValue%20em%20vez%20de%20value%20.) no React.